# How to install highlight.js using bower?

Tags: node.js, highlight, bower

The latest version of `highlight.js` is 8.4: https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/tree/8.4

When I try to install it using bower, I get version 7.0.1:

```
bower install highlight -S
bower install highlight-js -S
bower install highlight.js.origin -S
bower install git://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js.git -S
```

Even if I use `"git://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js.git#~8.4"` I can't do it:

```
bower highlight#~8.4        not-cached git://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js.git#~8.4
bower highlight#~8.4           resolve git://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js.git#~8.4
bower highlight#~8.4      ENORESTARGET No tag found that was able to satisfy ~8.4

Additional error details:
Available versions: 7.0.1, 6.0.1
```

How to install highlight.js 8.4 using bower?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shim-repository at https://github.com/components/highlightjs publishes the 8.4 version (and most later versions as well). So `bower install highlightjs` should do it.